# ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects | comparing values from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare values (that are all floats) from a constantly updated dataframe.

Here Ive separated each value out from the main dataframes:

```
if len(dfC) >= 3:

O = pd.DataFrame(dfO.tail(3))
O1 = (O.iloc[-1])
O2 = (O.iloc[-2])
O3 = (O.iloc[-3])

H = pd.DataFrame(dfH.tail(3))
H1 = (H.iloc[-1])
H2 = (H.iloc[-2])
H3 = (H.iloc[-3])

L = pd.DataFrame(dfL.tail(3))
L1 = (L.iloc[-1])
L2 = (L.iloc[-2])
L3 = (L.iloc[-3])

C = pd.DataFrame(dfC.tail(3))
C1 = (C.iloc[-1])
C2 = (C.iloc[-2])
C3 = (C.iloc[-3])
```

Here's where I am trying to compare them with eachother:

```
if (O2 <= C3) & (L2 >= O3) & (L1 >= C2) & (C1 >= O2):
    print("message")

elif (L2 >= C3) & (H2 <= O3) & (H1 <= C2) & (C1 <= O2):
    print("message")
```

However I get "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects". Thanks so much in advance, this is rather confusing me right now!

Comment: It is hard to tell anything without seeing the data (can you share samples?), but probably it wants to use the same index. Why do you need to convert the subsets into a dataframe?  You can try to get only the values by using the `.values` attribute (e.g. `df0.tail(3)` )

Comment: @nocibambi the data is open, high, low, close values for a  a stock. so they are all numbers ie. something like '3840.5'

Comment: In this case, the source of the problem seems not to be the data type of the actual values. Rather it is the difference between the indexes of the subsets you try to compare.

Comment: Well, from these I still cannot see the indexes :) You might want to copy some actual data. From this, it also seems that all four sets are actually the same dataframe (unless there is something else is going on).

Comment: Sorry, in my first comment I meant `df0.tailp(3).values`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Series/columns rather than DataFrame.

So instead of:

```
dfO = dfOHLCV.drop(dfOHLCV.columns[[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]], axis=1).reset_index() 

sO = dfOHLCV.iloc[:, 2]  # O is the 2th column.
O1 = sO.iloc[-1]
# etc.
```